# Incorrect handle class state within callback

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm facing a strange issue with a matlab handle class where state of the class is not the expected one when excecuting some callback.

To show the issue I oversimplified my class definition. Basic idea of this class is to create a user interface on top of settings which can be modified either from code or from user interaction.

Th problem is that I'm using a **java** combobox which will fire a **changed** event wheter selected index is modified from code or from user interaction ... ok ok ... very simple workaround i thought, I thus decided to add a `lockJavaEvent` property in my class in order to know if changed event is fired from code or from user interaction:

```
% Callback to listen to combo changed events
set(this.jcbFilterType, 'ActionPerformedCallback', @(s, e)this.onFilterTypeChanged(e)); 

% Code to refresh interface from code
function [] = refreshGuiFromCode(this)
%[
    this.lockJavaEvents = this.lockJavaEvents + 1;
    this.jcbFilterType.setSelectedIndex(this.filterTypeIndex - 1);            
    this.lockJavaEvents = this.lockJavaEvents - 1;
%]
end

% Code to respond to combox changed with quick exist in case it is changed from code
function [] = onFilterTypeChanged(this, e)
%[
    % Quick exit for events locked
    if (this.lockJavaEvents > 0),
        disp('Skipping combobox event because we are refreshing from code');
        return; 
    end

    ...
%]
end
```

Unfortunately this is not working at all ! When `refreshGuiFromCode` is called:

- As expected `this.lockJavaEvent` is increased to 1
- As expected, because I'm modifying combo index, the attached `onFilterTypeChanged` is called
- But patatra, within `onFilterTypeChanged` callback the value of `this.lockJavaEvent` is still equal to zero ????? !!!!

I clearly don't understand what's going on here ? Why is `this` object seems to be an old copy while my class is defined as a handle class ??

Here is my complete code for testing:

```
classdef BugLockJava <  hgsetget
%[    
    methods
        function [this] = BugLockJava()
        %[    
            this.lockJavaEvents = 0;
            this.filterTypeIndex = 2;

            this.buildGui();
            this.refreshGuiFromCode();
        %]                
        end
        function [] = delete(this)
        %[
            delete(this.parent);
        %]
        end
    end

    methods(Access = private)
        function [] = buildGui(this)
        %[    
            this.parent = figure();
            this.jcbFilterType = this.addJavaComboBox(); 

            this.jcbFilterType.setModel(javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel({'Sphere', 'Cylinder', 'Power', 'N&M'})); 
            this.jcbFilterType.setEditable(false);
            set(this.jcbFilterType, 'ActionPerformedCallback', @(s, e)this.onFilterTypeChanged(e)); 
        %]    
        end
        function [jComponent, hComponent, hContainer] = addJavaComboBox(this)
        %[
            % Create a matlab container to hold it 
            % NB: Required for uix, uiextras parents (GUILayout toolbox)
            hContainer = uicontainer('Parent', this.parent);
            position = getpixelposition(hContainer); position(1) = 0; position(2) = 0;

            % Link java component with visual tree in matlab
            [jComponent, hComponent] = javacomponent(javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JComboBox'), position, hContainer);
            set(hComponent, 'Units', 'normalized');

            % Turns java naked reference into a matlab component
            % http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks
            jComponent = handle(jComponent, 'CallbackProperties');            
        %]
        end
        function [] = refreshGuiFromCode(this)
        %[
            this.lockJavaEvents = this.lockJavaEvents + 1;
            this.jcbFilterType.setSelectedIndex(this.filterTypeIndex - 1);            
            this.lockJavaEvents = this.lockJavaEvents - 1;
        %]
        end
        function [] = onFilterTypeChanged(this, e)
        %[
            % Quick exit for events locked
            if (this.lockJavaEvents > 0),
                disp('Skipping combobox event because we are refreshing from code');
                return; 
            end

            % Quick exist for action unknown
            cmd = char(e.getActionCommand());
            if (~strcmpi(cmd, 'comboBoxChanged')), 
                disp('Skipping combobox event because we don''t care');
                return; 
            end

            disp('Ok combobox changed from user interaction');
            this.filterTypeIndex = this.jcbFilterType.getSelectedIndex() + 1;                        
        %]
        end
    end


    properties %%% Keeping public for debugging values (Access = private)
        parent;
        jcbFilterType;
        lockJavaEvents;

        filterTypeIndex;
    end
%]    
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !!!

[image: Unsynchronized]

Look how strangely is placed the yellow arrow while executing `onFilterTypeChanged` callback ... It is as if `refreshGuiFromCode` had continue executing after `setSelectedIndex` .... java callback is only executed in the end and this because it is **ON ANOTHER THREAD / MESSAGE PUMP**

To fix the issue I simply added a call to `drawnow()` to force pending events in the message pump to execute before to go ahead:

[image: Synchronized]

That really was a strange issue ... but anyway easy to fix when keeping in mind that java components are on another ui thread.